# How to stop an eventListener to do actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following events but when I click on close-button I don't want activate mouseover until mouseleave is done. So I click close button, it collapse but when is collapsed, even if I don't move the mouse, it still continue to expand. So I want to hold collapse until mouseleave then I can mouseover.

```
function addEventListeners() {
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseover", isClicked);
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseleave", collapse);
    document.getElementById("close-button").addEventListener("click", collapse);        
    document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", clickthrough);
    document.getElementById("replay").addEventListener("click", replay);
    if(isIphone) document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("click", function(){collapse()});
}
```

Comment: [`.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Removing the listener is one way. The other is to have the mouseover handler set a global variable, and have the other handlers check that before doing anything.

Comment: @Andreas I understand that this is the method but I can't figure out how this is going to be applied in my code as I've done this document.getElementById("close-button")addEventListener("click", document.getElementById("container").removeEventListener('mouseover'), collapse);

Comment: Please don't tag question with `jQuery` unless you want a jQuery answer (i.e. just use `off()` and `on()`). :)